# Parse JSON in Google Refine

Tags: json, parsing, google-refine

I'm trying to pull out specific elements from results from the Data Science Toolkit coordinates2politics API, using Google Refine.

Here is sample cell #1:

```
[{"politics":[
 {"type":"admin2","friendly_type":"country","code":"usa","name":"United States"},
 {"type":"admin6","friendly_type":"county","code":"55_025","name":"Dane"},
 {"type":"constituency","friendly_type":"constituency","code":"55_02","name":"Second district, WI"},
 {"type":"admin5","friendly_type":"city","code":"55_48000","name":"Madison"},
 {"type":"admin5","friendly_type":"city","code":"55_53675","name":"Monona"},
 {"type":"admin4","friendly_type":"state","code":"us55","name":"Wisconsin"},
 {"type":"neighborhood","friendly_type":"neighborhood","code":"Eastmorland|Madison|WI","name":"Eastmorland"}
 ],"location":{"longitude":"-89.3259404","latitude":"43.0859191"}}]
```

I added a column based on this column using this GREL syntax to pull out the county, Dane:

```
value.parseJson()[0]["politics"][1]["name"]
```

But when I got to Sample Cell #2, the syntax no longer works because the JSON result is a little different:

```
[{"politics":[
 {"type":"admin2","friendly_type":"country","code":"usa","name":"United States"},
 {"type":"constituency","friendly_type":"constituency","code":"55_05","name":"Fifth district, WI"},
 {"type":"admin4","friendly_type":"state","code":"us55","name":"Wisconsin"},
 {"type":"admin6","friendly_type":"county","code":"55_079","name":"Milwaukee"},
 {"type":"admin5","friendly_type":"city","code":"55_84675","name":"Wauwatosa"},
 {"type":"constituency","friendly_type":"constituency","code":"55_04","name":"Fourth district, WI"}
 ],"location":{"longitude":"-88.0075875","latitude":"43.0494572"}}]
```

Is there some way to sort the JSON or phrase my syntax so that I can find the county in either case?

#### Update

Here's the magic GREL that allowed me to find elements in the JSON string by name, not just position:

```
filter(value.parseJson()[0]["politics"], item, item["type"]=="admin6")[0]["name"]
```

Comment: What do you want as an output?

Comment: Output should be the county name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The field named `politics` is an array, which you return with:

```
value.parseJson()[0]["politics"]
```

One element of that array is associated with the county (it's the one whose `friendly_type` field is "county"). So you need to filter the `politics` field to find the one whose `friendly_type` is county, like this:

```
filter(value.parseJson()[0]["politics"], item, item["friendly_type"]=="county")
```

That returns an array with one element. You want to get the `name` field out of that one element, so you need to extract the `name` of the zeroth array element, making your complete expression:

```
filter(value.parseJson()[0]["politics"], item, item["friendly_type"]=="county")[0]["name"]
```