# Google Refine: iterate over a JSON dictionary

Tags: json, dictionary, openrefine

I've got some JSON within Google Refine - http://mapit.mysociety.org/point/4326/0.1293497,51.5464828 for the full version, but abbreviated it's like this:

```
{1234: {'name': 'Barking', 'type': 'WMC'},
 5678: {'name': 'England', 'type': 'EUR'} }
```

I only want to extract the name for the object with the (presumed unique) type `WMC`.

[Parse JSON in Google Refine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10304238/parse-json-in-google-refine) doesn't help, that's working with arrays, not dicts.

Any suggestions what I should be looking at to fix this?

---

**Edit**: I don't know what the initial keys are: I believe they're unique identifiers which I can't predict ahead of time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Refine doesn't currently know how to iterate through the keys of a dict where they keys are unknown (although I'm about to implement that functionality).

The trick to getting this working with the current implementation is to convert the JSON object to a JSON array.  The following GREL expression will do that, parse the result as JSON, iterate through all elements of the array and give you the first name of type 'WMC'.

```
filter(('['+(value.replace(/"[0-9]+":/,""))[1,-1]+']').parseJson(),v,v['type']=='WMC')[0]['name']
```

Use that expression with the "Add column based on this column" command to create a new WMC name column.  If there's a chance that there'll be more than one name of this type and you want them all, you can add in a forEach loop and join along the lines of

```
forEach(filter(('['+(value.replace(/"[0-9]+":/,""))[1,-1]+']').parseJson(),v,v['type']=='WMC'),x,x['name']).join('|')
```

This will give you a pipe separated list of names that you can split apart using "Split multi-valued cells."

It'll be easier in the next release hopefully!

Comment: slightly out of topic. Are you planning to let people use plain JavaScript? with a simple js program of no more than 3 lines it would be pretty easy and simple to achieve. (BTW, whay did you choose GREL over plain js with some added functions?)